# How to replace DOCTYPE element in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My input file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">
<book>
    <name>ABC</name>
</book>
```

I want to change the `DOCTYPE` element (commented - see below):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd"> -->
<book>
    <name>ABC</name>
</book>
```

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if we can do xml manipulation. Here what you can do with string manipulation

```
a='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">
<book>
<name>ABC</name>
</book>'''
lis=a.split('\n')
for i,j in zip(lis,range(len(lis))):
    if i.startswith('<!DOCTYPE'):
        i = '<!--'+i+'-->'
        lis[j]=i
a='\n'.join(lis)
```

If it does not have anything to split on.

```
a='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd"><book><name>ABC</name></book>'
str1=""
start=a.index('<!DOCTYPE')
end=a.index('>',start)
str1=a[:start]
str1+='<!--'+'<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">'+'-->'
str1+=a[end+1:]
str1 #'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!--<!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd">--><book><name>ABC</name></book>'
```

Comment: Your answer is work correctly but you know that I want to change doctype element if doctyoe element is coming in third line than your code is fail.

Comment: Ok if all element is coming in one line then.

Comment: Then split by space if it is really an xml. Otherwise, edit the question with all the possibilities.

Comment: Check this code. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!DOCTYPE note SYSTEM "Note.dtd"><book><name>ABC</name></book>

Comment: You should consider editing the question rather than commenting here and quizzing me. It brings less help to the future readers. The best approach in that case would be regex

Comment: see edit again and do edit your question to make it more clear

Comment: Sorry mad. I am not quizing you I think you are not read my first comment and my question. I told you your answer is correct you are thinking good but my requirement is different I want to work in XML file I don't know doctype element is where or not or which line or not. In this case your code is not work properly.